# How to implement geocoding in a Meteor app form submission?

Tags: meteor, geocoding

I have a user submitted form with a location field. I want to call the Google Geocoding API and get the latitude and longitude of the location to ensure the location exists and then send all three pieces of data to the db.

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    alert(results[0].geometry.location);
  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

The only place I can find to get this code to alert the correct coordinates is in my collections posts.js file, but it also is causing a server error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'post' ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Comment: Have you referenced the google apis in your `<head>..</head>` section?

Comment: Yep, the coordinates are coming in. I just am not sure where I should place the geocoding code in my files and how to prevent the server error.

Comment: Oh I see, you're running this on the server? You would need to use some kind of server side plugin, such as (npm)-https://npmjs.org/package/geocoder as the google geocoder api is client side only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoding should be done in the add post page manager (client side only). Because the geocoding call is asynchronous, I wasn't getting a response before posting to the db. Moving the db post inside the success branch of the geocode function fixed it.

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': pin.location}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        pin.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        pin.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        Meteor.call('post', pin, function(error, id){
            if (error)
                return alert(error.reason);

            Meteor.Router.to('pinPage', pin);
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```